# Quantify product-appropriateness score

Tags: calculus

I'm looking for a way to quantify and explain the scenario below to my managers. I'm really good at understanding issues, but unfortunately no so good at communicating them to others. I have written some code that works out scores or should I save appropriateness of a product for a customer.  I now need to explain how this works to my non-technical managers (visually) I was think via a math formula?

Can anyone help out?

The best way to explain what I have is...

```
**PRODUCT** 
Ball 

Must have Bat
Must be age 8-99
```

---

```
**PERSON**
Jake
age 30

Score = 50%
```

the system looks at the total possible score for product. In the case of Bat this is 2 (because we have two possible requirements for bat). Person has just one matching item. So the product appropriateness would come out as 50%.

Here is another example...

```
**PRODUCT** 
House 

Must be a person
Must be age 18-65
Must be employed
Must have Money
```

---

```
**PERSON**
John

is a person **edit**
age 16
has Money
is employed

Score = 75%
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your second example score is wrong; it should be 75%. Also, I'd remove the Calculus tag; this has very little to do with calculus.

Comment: Its 50% as John only meets two conditions out of 4, he is only 16 where he needs to be between 18-65 for a house.

Comment: Doesn't John meet three of the four conditions?  Yes, the age criterion is not met, but it appears the other three are.

Comment: ok, I see the issue with person and it's confusing, sorry. I will just assume John is a person and I'll change it to have person in John's table. making 3, sorry bout that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\textrm{Score} = \frac{\textrm{Number of Conditions Met}}{\textrm{Number of Conditions Required}}$$

Comment: How simple, how perfect!